# MonoDevelop reports Build Successful but there is no exe file

Tags: mono, monodevelop

In MonoDevelop, I create a new solution (C# console application).
It gives me a simple hello world program.
I press the run button.
I see "Build Successful"
The terminal comes up and says:

```
Cannot open assembly '/home/beauxq/MonoProjects/cstest/cstest/bin/Debug/cstest.exe': No such file or directory.

Press any key to continue...
```

I look in that bin/Debug directory and it is empty.

The build output:

```
Building: cstest (Debug|x86)

Build started 7/28/2016 9:29:40 AM.
__________________________________________________
Project "/home/beauxq/MonoProjects/cstest/cstest/cstest.csproj" (Build target(s)):

    Target PrepareForBuild:
        Configuration: Debug Platform: x86

    Target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies:
    No input files were specified for target GenerateSatelliteAssemblies, skipping.

    Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
    Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because its outputs are up-to-date.
Done building project "/home/beauxq/MonoProjects/cstest/cstest/cstest.csproj".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.
     0 Warning(s)

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build successful.
```

The same happens when I select "Build" from the menu. "Build Successful" but the directory is empty.

Comment: did you make progress?

Answer (score 1):

It's nice to specify your linux/unix distribution. Or create the bug in their bugtracker. They will decide is it packaging problem or upstream problem. If this is upstream problem, maintainers will create bug in monodevelop bugtracker.